# How to prove (quickly) equivalence between those two conic section definitions?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Here is probably a very stupid question, but I couldn't find the answer myself. Also, I was unable of finding anywhere.

I bet all of you knows this obvious stuff that you are about to read, but I'll write anyway: Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ and $F$ to be arbitrarily non-coincident points. Let $L$ and $D$ be the directrix lines such that $F\notin L$ and $F\notin D$. The point $P$ belongs to the conic section. Notation $d(A, B)$ means the distance between geometrical objects $A$ and $B$ (points or lines).

$$
\mbox{Conics: }
\begin{cases}
\mbox{Ellipse: } && d(P, F_1) + d(P, F_2) = 2a \\
\mbox{Hyperbola: } && d(P, F_1) - d(P, F_2) = 2a \\
\mbox{Parabola: } && d(P, F) = d(P, L) \\
\end{cases}
$$

For the appropriate values of $\epsilon$, we have each of those conics, with a single equivalent definition:
$$d(P, F) = \epsilon\cdot d(P, D)$$.

Well, one can prove it by selecting point $P = (x, y)$, making the proper equations, with a few simplifications, on the first definition, and on the second, and show they are the same.

**Here is my question:** How can one prove equivalence between those two definitions very quickly? Efortlessly?

Also, if you are feeling generous, perhaps you can tell me: is there a way of proving this, using the whole time the $d(A, B)$ notation? How?  =).

---

**The little of what I got:**

The proof for parabola is obvious. Then, basically, we have:
$$
\mbox{Conics: }
\begin{cases}
\mbox{Ellipse: } 
&& d(P, F_1) = 2a - d(P, F_2) = \epsilon\cdot d(P, D),
&& \epsilon < 1 \\
\mbox{Hyperbola: } 
&& d(P, F_1) = 2a + d(P, F_2) = \epsilon\cdot d(P, D),
&& \epsilon > 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Thus, we are basically proving that, for fixed point $F$, fixed line $D$, fixed constant $a>0$, there exists $\epsilon$ such that:
$$
2a \pm d(P, F) = \epsilon\cdot d(P, D), 
\quad\forall P\in\mathbb{R}^2
$$

Well.. that's it. I couldn't progress further. I'll edit if I make progresses....

Comment: Actually, I've never seen the second formula for conic sections. What would be appropriate values of $\epsilon$ for ellipses and hyperbolas? Furthermore, what are $F$ and $D$ (geometrically) for ellipses and hyperbolas?

Comment: @A.P. The value $\epsilon$ is called eccentricity of the conic section. For $0\le\epsilon < 1$, it become an ellipse. For $\epsilon>1$ become an hyperbola. $F$ is the foci. $D$ is a directrix line.

Comment: I didn't use the same variables you did, but I've proved this statement for ellipses and hyperbolas [in this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833973/prove-that-the-directrix-focus-and-focus-focus-definitions-are-equivalent).